# Changing the position of a Power Apps Form to the middle of the page

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps

When I create a new PowerApps form, a separate window is pulled up, but I cannot move it to the middle of my screen- it seems locked to the right.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box solution to adjust the location of the Native SharePoint List form or the PowerApps form. You may look into forms using InfoPath or custom Css